# ISO 8601 String to NSDate

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to convert a date string in this format `2014-07-07T17:57:09.525-07:00` to an NSDate. So far I've tried the following but it's returning null. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: You are missing out the milliseconds. Try `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing milliseconds. Change this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

To this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"];
```

Reference (highly recommend that you bookmark it): [Link](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)