# dateFromString returns nil after using rfc3339dateFormatter as an example in iOS Documentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get NSDate from NSString by parsing in following manner:

```
NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSString *createdString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2014-08-27T17:10:36.000+05:30"];
NSDate *createdDate = [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:createdString];
```

Here createdDate is being returned as nil. What am I missing here? Also please clarify me proper usage of timeZone and locale.

Comment: You are missing milliseconds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225977/iso-8601-string-to-nsdate#comment39292950_25225977

Comment: Great. It works absolutely fine after that. Also do I need to specify timezones and locale for any reason or to avoid any crash? I guess by default it shows according to local timezone. Please post it as an answer so I shall checkmark it. thanks a bunch!

Comment: You may post it as a answer so I would accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Right Date Formatter

Use This Line:

```
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"];
```

in Place of this:

```
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
```