# Unexpected behavior with NSDateFormatter on iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I have this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString *sDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:_datePicker];
```

_datePicker comes from this and datePicker is a UIDatePicker

```
_datePicker = datePicker.date;
```

This was working ok in iOS 7 fore sure, and now I'm testing in 9.1

So if the phone settings is set to show the time in the 24h format its ok, but if I change the settings to none 24h format I have a estrange behavior:

if is set to 24h the output is:

[image]

But if i change it to non 24h is:

[image]

[image]

As you can see is like is combining the 2 formats it adds for example the 13 of the 1 pm to the hour 131:00 or at 6 pm will be 186:00.

Is there a work around to always get the time in the 24h format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try without `setLocale:`

Comment: @Cy-4AH Thanks but the result is the same without setLocale:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have sean this approach in another page and I have change the code to this:

```
NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z"];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSString *sDate = [rfc3339DateFormatter stringFromDate: _datePicker];
```

And now is working properly but I'm not sure that this is the correct way.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

**UPDATE:** [This is where I got the code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625183/datefromstring-returns-nil-after-using-rfc3339dateformatter-as-an-example-in-ios)

Comment: Some information on why en_US_POSIX should be used for the locale: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html